# Which machine learning technique suits this use case?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas

I have two different zones say for ex. IN and OUT and each zone with two features i.e., A & B. Now I have a target with the same two features and with the help of this, I need to identify, to which zone the target belongs to?

Following are the data set which I have for sample demonstration purpose. In actual scenario, I will have approximately 200 samples for each feature.

```
IN_A,IN_B,OUT_A,OUT_B,Target_A,Target_B
-28, -73, -81,  -34,  -31,     -69
-31, -71, -76,  -37,  -35,     -68
-33, -69, -78,  -32,  -29,     -63
-35, -68, -79,  -38,  -36,     -66
-37, -70, -77,  -39,  -32,     -67
-34, -72, -75,  -36,  -34,     -65
-39, -65, -74,  -35,  -38,     -61
-41, -63, -72,  -40,  -33,     -63
-45, -61, -73,  -43,  -45,     -64
-48, -60, -71,  -42,  -40,     -62
-43, -64, -70,  -41,  -37,     -60
-42, -62, -69,  -44,  -43,     -59
-46, -59, -68,  -46,  -46,     -58
-44, -58, -67,  -45,  -41,     -57
-49, -57, -66,  -47,  -44,     -56
```

The above data set has plotted, Now with the help of this I need to identify to which zone the target belongs to? Which machine learning algorithm suites well for this?
[image]

Note: The number of samples in target need not to be equal to the training data set.

Comment: What are those 6 variables in your sample data? What variables are you using to classify these objects? What is RSSI-A and RSSI-B?

Comment: RSSI value for inward direction from gateway A and gateway B are IN_A & IN_B and RSSI value for outward direction from gateway A and gateway B are OUT_A & OUT_B. Now I have the target RSSI value from gateway A and gateway B, with these I need to identify the target belongs to inward or outward direction.

Comment: I don't really understand, but this looks like it could be solved with clustering.

Comment: Did that help? Is clustering working?